# TurboPower LockBox how can one use AES with a byte array as key

Tags: turbopower, lockbox-3

I want to encrypt a file but i have the key as a byte array. I do not want to use a password.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the TCodec.InitFromStream() method.
Refer to the [on-line help](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/LB3Help_TCodec_InitFromStream).

Also see the [tutorial](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/Encrypt+a+file) on encrypting a file.

Comment: Thx. I have now another problem